# Send Multipart message with android

Tags: java, android, email, multipart, rfc822

I have a rfc822 message I have created in Android. I need to send it via email to the specified recipients:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("message/rfc822");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, emailAddresses.toArray(new String[0]));

    LightMimeEntity lightMimeEntity = makeMessage();

    byte[] messageBytes = getMessageAsByteArray(lightMimeEntity);

    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, new String(messageBytes));

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send mail..."));
```

This causes GMail to crash with a `NullPointerException`.

If I replace

```
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, new String(messageBytes));
```

with

```
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, new String(messageBytes));
```

it uses the rfc822 text as the message body, which is not satisfactory.

Is there a way to send a message of this type through the Android email system?